# Is Postfix required for WordPress contact forms in general?

Tags: email, contact, linux, smtp

If I remember correctly, I could get data from `ContactForm7`, for example, into my personal Gmail account, without doing `apt-get install postfix -y`, though I might be wrong and I did install it.

I don't have a ready testing environment so I can't confirm now, hence my question:

Is Postfix required for WordPress ContactForms in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Postfix if you use an SMTP plugin like, for example, [WP Mail SMTP](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/). Such kind of plugins can send email from your Google account via SMTP.

I have just checked it by stopping postfix and successfully sending an email via WP Mail SMTP.

If no SMTP plugins are activated on your site, you definitely need system transport, which can be Postfix or another mail transfer agent (MTA) on Linux. Postfix also can send your emails using your Google account as a relay.

Comment: Thanks KAGG. I understood everything besides this `Postfix also can send your emails using your Google account as a relay.`. Care to elaborate?

Comment: You can read this article https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-as-a-mail-relay/. Or ask another question here and I will be happy to share my Postfix config.